# Get a series of commits on a detached head onto a branch

Tags: git

I have five commits on a detached head. I can't `--set-upstream`, because I'm not on a branch. Do I need to checkout a fresh branch, and cherry pick and commit all five of them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rose, it looks like you can just make a new branch

```
If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch new_branch_name <SHA of fifth commit>
```