# Make commits in detached head state, how do I apply them to a branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-checkout

I did a git checkout  and made some changes while in the detached head state.  I commited the changes.  How do I apply these changes to a specific branch?  Can I checkout that branch and then do a git merge?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a new branch

```
If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch new_branch_name <SHA of commit>
```

[Get a series of commits on a detached head onto a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15673571/get-a-series-of-commits-on-a-detached-head-ont)